# Split grouped observations in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dictionary, mydict, contains several dataframes. Each dataframe contains varying number of observation but the same number of features. VARIABLEx is both key in the dictionary and the first feature in the dataframe. VARIABLEx may be numeric, a character, or numeric character (varnum) and there may be a “natural” ranking/ordering or not.

[image: {'VARIABLE1': VARIABLE1 Product1 Product2 Product3 0 3 111 999 102 1 2 98 999 104 2 4 97 999 98 3 5 105 999 95 4 1 85 999 110 5 6 101 999 98 6 1--3 999 101 999 7 4--6 999 102 999, 'VARIABLE2': VARIABLE2 Product1 Product2 Product3 0 Total 105 98 100}]

My question is about VARIABLE1 in the table above (if it can't show I have provided code below). The variable contains values like 1, 2, ... 6, but also 1--3 and 4--6; PRODUCT1 and PRODUCT3 contains real values when VARIABLE1 adheres to the first “syntax” (1, 2, 3, …6), however 999 (NaN-value) when VARIABLE1 i adheres to the latter. FOr PRODUCT2 it is the opposite.

What I would like is this:

mydict:
[image: {'VARIABLE1': VARIABLE1 Product1 Product2 Product3 0 3 111 101 102 1 2 98 101 104 2 4 97 101 98 3 5 105 102 95 4 1 85 102 110 5 6 101 102 98 'VARIABLE2': VARIABLE2 Product1 Product2 Product3 0 Total 105 98 100}]

i.e. the “real values” of PRODUCT2 replaces the “999” for corresponding observation [1,2,3][4,5,6] and the "grouped values" ([1--3] and [4--6]) are removed from the dataframe.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
mydict = {}

dict1 = {'VARIABLE1': ['3', '2', '4', '5', '1', '6', '1--3', '4--6'], 
        'Product1': [111, 98, 97, 105, 85, 101, 999, 999] ,
        'Product2': [999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 999, 101, 102] ,
        'Product3': [102, 104, 98, 95, 110, 98, 999, 999]}
dict2 = {'VARIABLE2': ['Total'], 
        'Product1': [105],
        'Product2': [98],
        'Product3': [100]}

mydict['VARIABLE1'] = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
mydict['VARIABLE2'] = pd.DataFrame(dict2)


print('\n mydict: ')
mydict
```

Comment: Does [1--3] indicates values of VARIABLE1 or just cunsecutive number of row? What is role of mydict['VARIABLE2'], because no calculations are made on it?

Comment: 1--3 is a string, however, the implied meaning is consecutive numbers (1,2,3) - it could also be 1--8 (= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8).
VARIABLE2 does not play any direct role, however, serve to illustrate that the dataframe exists within a dictionary with other dataframes -> I would expect a solution that a) pull the dataframe out, 2) manipulate the dataframe/ create a new dataframe with the desired structure 3) replace the old dataframe within the dictionary 
(but that is just my approach there may be others)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step: first define `df` we are working on:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

separate into 2 dataframes:

```
dft = df[df.VARIABLE1.str.contains('--')]
df =  df[~df.VARIABLE1.str.contains('--')]
```

then convert strings to lists using `split`, next transform to ranges by using `lambda` function, and create new rows using [`expode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method. Result store in `df.Product2`:

```
df.Product2 = dft.assign(VAR1=dft['VARIABLE1'].str.split('--')\
                  .map(lambda r: range(int(r[0]),int(r[1])+1) ))\
                  .explode('VAR1').Product2.values
```

output dataframe `df`:

```
  VARIABLE1  Product1  Product2  Product3
0         3       111       101       102
1         2        98       101       104
2         4        97       101        98
3         5       105       102        95
4         1        85       102       110
5         6       101       102        98
```

You can finally write back dataframe to dictionary:

```
mydict['VARIABLE1'] = df
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you!